# Generating a Random Asymmetric Binary Tree with N Leaf Nodes and Depth D Efficiently

Tags: algorithm, math, tree

I'm working on a project where I need to generate a random binary tree. The tree should have N leaf nodes and be within some specified depth D. However, I'm struggling to find an efficient way to generate a random binary tree that is both asymmetric and well-distributed while ensuring it has exactly N leaves.

My current approach involves repeatedly generating random trees within a certain range until I find one with the correct number of leaf nodes. However, this method seems inefficient and slow.

Can anyone suggest a more efficient algorithm or approach to achieve this goal? I'd appreciate any insights or code examples that can help me generate such a tree efficiently.

Comment: Why can't you count N leaf nodes  as you build the binary tree and don't allow it to go past depth D (dropping any nodes that would on the floor)? Any terminal node counts towards N and any node with a descendent doesn't. It is highly unlikely that a tree built using random numbers will be anything other than asymmetric and well distributed. Or do you have some as yet unspecified asymmetry in mind?

Comment: I have tried making this but this approach doesnt seem to make it so that the binary tree always has N leaves so nothing less and nothing more

Comment: Do these nodes have distinct values, or is it just the shape of the tree that interests you?

Comment: To me this question is unclear. What do you mean by **random binary tree**? Random values? Or ?

Comment: I don't see how it can fail. You increment N only when the parent node that you are adding to already has a non-null pointer on the other branch. If both the parent 's pointers are nil then the inserted node becomes a new leaf and the parent ceases to be a leaf so that N remains the same.

Comment: You could do a rotation when the tree exceeds the maximum allowed depth, by searching up towards the parent, to find a node whose other branch does not descend to the maximum depth already. If no such node exists  then you will need to traverse the other branch of the root node looking for the nodes at maximum depth and perform the same operation to decrease their depths by one. After that operation, it should be possible to do the rotation of the original branch.

Comment: Adding to @trincot's question, if the shape matters, what matters about it? Is a single threaded tree that goes left-left-left different than right-right-right? (If so, any leaves are very likely to go down to close to depth `d`, even if it makes no sense for them to do so.)

Answer (score 2):

You could take this approach:

1. Define a Node class with an additional `depth` field so to ease the following algorithm.
2. Create the root node, and put it in a set.
3. Choose a random node from the set, and remove it from the set. This node will become the parent of a new node. If that parent is currently a leaf, then choose randomly whether the new node will become its left or right child. If that parent already had a child, then make the new node the sibling of that child. The new node will get a depth that is one more than its parent has.
4. If the parent now has two children, then it means the number of leaves in the tree increased by one. If the number of leaves has been achieved, then we're done.
5. If the parent just has the one child now, and the number of leaves has not yet been achieved, then put it back in the set.
6. If the new node's depth is less than the desired tree height, then add it to the set.
7. Repeat from step 3 until the number of leaves has been achieved.

To avoid that this favours smaller trees too much, we could continue the loop also when we already have the required number of leaves, but not have not reached the maximum height. The decision to continue could be random. If we continue, the choice for next parent node should be made from leaves only, as otherwise we would increase the number of leaves.

This will not produce a *perfect* distribution among the possible trees, but it might be good enough for what you need.

We can add an symmetry-test on top of this, so to rerun the algorithm if this is the case.

Here is an implementation of the above idea in an interactive JavaScript snippet. You can adjust the parameters (number of leaves and tree height), and the algorithm will produce a tree with those constraints:

```js
class Node {
    constructor(depth) {
        this.depth = depth; // ...to ease algorithm
        this.children = [null, null]; // left and right
    }
}

const isLeaf = node => !node.children[0] && !node.children[1];

const serialize = (root) =>
    root ? `[${root.children.map(serialize).join("")}]` : "[]";

const serializeMirror = (root) =>
    root ? `[${root.children.toReversed().map(serializeMirror).join("")}]` : "[]";

const isSymmetric = (root) => serialize(root) === serializeMirror(root);

// Utility to extract a chosen element from an array
function extract(arr, i) {
    const value = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr.at(-1); // Swap last to this index
    arr.pop(); // Reduce array length
    return value;
}

const randInt = (n) => Math.floor(Math.random() * n);

// Main algorithm
function createTree(numLeaves, maxHeight) {
    if (numLeaves >= 2**maxHeight || numLeaves < 1 || maxHeight < 1) {
        throw Error(`There's no asymmetric binary tree with these constraints`);
    }
    if (numLeaves == 0) return null; // Empty tree
    let choices = [];
    const root = new Node(0);
    choices.push(root);
    let height = 0;
    let curLeaves = 1;
    while (curLeaves < numLeaves || randInt(maxHeight - height + 1) > 0) {
        const parent = extract(choices, randInt(choices.length));
        let childIndex = randInt(2);
        if (parent.children[childIndex]) childIndex = 1 - childIndex;
        const node = parent.children[childIndex] = new Node(parent.depth + 1);
        if (parent.children[1 - childIndex]) { // Has two children?
            curLeaves++;
            if (curLeaves === numLeaves) { // Don't allow the creation of more leaves
                choices = choices.filter(isLeaf);
            }            
        } else if (curLeaves < numLeaves) { // Has one child, and we need leaves
            choices.push(parent);
        }
        if (node.depth < maxHeight) {
            choices.push(node);
        }
        height = Math.max(height, node.depth);
    }
    // Final symmetry check: retry if so...
    if (isSymmetric(root)) return createTree(numLeaves, maxHeight);
    return root;
}

// Utility for rendering the tree in a readable format
function treeString(root, trace="") {
    if (!root) return "";
    let tab = " ".repeat(root.depth.toString().length);
    return treeString(root.children[1], trace.replaceAll("┌", " ").replaceAll("└", "│") 
                                        + tab + "┌")
         + trace + root.depth + " ┐┘┤"[2*!!root.children[1] + !!root.children[0]] + "\n"
         + treeString(root.children[0], trace.replaceAll("┌", "│").replaceAll("└", " ")
                                        + tab + "└");
}

function rotateString(s) {  // Used to get the root at the top
    const lines = s.split("\n");
    const result = [];
    const len = Math.max(...lines.map(({length}) => length));
    for (const line of lines) {
        Array.from(line.padEnd(len), (ch, i) => (result[i] ??= []).push(ch))
    }
    return result.map(row => row.join("")).join("\n")
            .replace(/[│┌└┤┘┐]/g, c => "─┌┐┴┘└"["│┌└┤┘┐".indexOf(c)]);
}

// I/O handling
const [inpLeaveCount, inpHeight, btnGo, output] = document.querySelectorAll("input, button, pre");

function refresh() {
    const numLeaves = +inpLeaveCount.value;
    const height = +inpHeight.value;
    try {
        const root = createTree(numLeaves, height);
        output.textContent = rotateString(treeString(root));
    } catch(e) {
        output.textContent = e.message;
    }
}
(document.oninput = btnGo.onclick = refresh)();
```

```css
input { width: 3em }
```

```html
Number of leaves: <input type="number" value="10" min="1">
Maximum height: <input type="number" value="5" min="1"> 
<button>Generate</button><br>
<pre></pre>
```

Comment: I think the OP only needs the tree to be within D, not exactly D, so you can kill "|| !hasHeight" in the main while statement. Also, this is very likely to generate an asymmetric tree for reasonable inputs, but it isn't guaranteed.

Comment: Ah, right, I somehow understood the tree had to have the exact given height. But you're right. Updated the text and code accordingly.

Comment: As to symmetry, this could be open for interpretation. I added logic that rejects solutions where the root's left subtree is the mirror of the root's right subtree. I also re-instated some of the code I removed after the first comment, so to increase the probability to generate higher trees (still within the constraints).